# TypeScript type for object where values must be one of the keys?

Tags: typescript, object, types

Let's say I want to store data about who's who's best friend in a group of people. I could model it like this:

```
const bestFriends: BestFriends = {
  "Lisa": "Peter",
  "Mark": "Peter",
  "Peter": "Lisa",
}
```

So Lisa's best friend is Peter, and so on. Now I want to put a TypeScript type on this - how should `BestFriends` be defined? My first approach would be:

```
// Alt #1: Not strict enough.
interface BestFriends {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

However, this comes with no guarantee that best friends will be within the group. I want the type system to guarantee that for me. The best I have been able to come up with is this:

```
// Alt #2: Requires dublicate name lists.
type Person = "Lisa" | "Mark" | "Peter"
type BestFriends = Record<Person, Person>
```

This works, but I am not satisfied. I have to maintain two lists of names - one in the type `Person`, and one in the keys of `bestFriends`. I would prefer if I could somehow just list the names once,  like in this non-compiling code:

```
// Alt #3: Does not compile.
interface BestFriends {
    [key: K]: K
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Replacing with constants would be of no use in TS. And I don't think it would make any difference for the question here. Replacing with an object representing the person in question is not an option in the context I am working.

Comment: I didn't say anything about constants. I would expect people's names to be user input / read from a DB / read file files / etc., e.g., strings. I mean, if you have the use case, you have the use case, it's just surprising.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, I see, I made unwarranted assumptions. It's not actually people and names, just had to make it about something that sort of made sense in a MCVE. Full story is to long for this comment! :-)